# How can I concate address line 1,2,3 and city in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am using `CONCAT(CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_LINE1||,' ',CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_LINE2||,' ',CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_LINE3||,' ',CUSTOMER_CITY)` but I am getting error message as Missing expressions.

Comment: [Concatenation Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Concatenation-Operator.html#GUID-08C10738-706B-4290-B7CD-C279EBC90F7E)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing operators.  Just use || to do all the concatenation:

```
CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_LINE1||' '||
CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_LINE2||' ' ||
CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_LINE3||' '||
CUSTOMER_CITY
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_LINE1 || ' '
    || CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_LINE2 || ' '
    || CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_LINE3 || ' '
    || CUSTOMER_CITY
from table ..
```